# ngRoute XMLHttpRequest

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I've installed node.js and used npm to run a http server via node.js and my ngRoutes are still bad when I try to click on login or register on my app im following via a angular tutorial. I've used chrome and firefox :(

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp' , ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, previous, error){

    if (error== 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {

        $rootScope.message= 'Sorry you need to login first to access this page';
        $location.path('/login');
    }//Authenticatoin Required
}); //Route changed error
}]); //run

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {

        templateUrl:    'views/login.html',
        controller:     'RegistrationController'
    }).
    when('/register', {

        templateUrl:    'views/registration.html',
        controller:     'RegistrationController'

 }).
        when('/success', {
        templateUrl:    'views/Success.html',
        controller:     'SuccessController',
        resolve:         {

            currentAuth: function(Authentication) {

                return Authentication.requireAuth();
            }//currentAuth -- Set the resolve method to make sure there is a current user before
            //allowing someone to go to this page
        }//resolve
}).
```

and here is my links for the nav, why isnt it working even when I toggle CORS on Chrome.

```
  <div><a ng-href="#/">tudu</a>
 </div>
 <ul>
<li ng-hide ="currentUser" ><a ng-href="#/login">Login</a></li>
<li ng-hide ="currentUser"><a  ng-href="#/register">Register</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I think some code is missing to be able to solve this

Comment: sorry what else you need , thats pretty much the full app.js , and the links that control the views , what else should I put up Rudolf.

Comment: Do you have any error message in console? What's the url of your app? When you click what's the network call?

Comment: none , giving me a error for trying to access the user information once I log out the test app but thats' fine I can set the security setting in firebase to make that go away but when I click on resgister , this the URL I get: 

http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html#!/login#%2Fregister

instead of 

http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html#!/register 

which actually works.